# bxSlider.js - displaying only one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have this code:

```
function slideshow(){
    $allfilesslides = glob(SITE_ROOT."/img/slideshow_slide*.png");
    $file_num_slide = count($allfilesslides)+1;
    if($file_num_slide > 0){
        echo '<div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider">';

        for($i = 1; $i < $file_num_slide; $i++){
            echo "<li><a href='img/slideshow_slide$i.png'><img src='img/slideshow_slide$i.png' /></a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></div>";
    } else{
        echo "";
    }
}
```

But it only displays one slide when I run the `slideshow` function.

Comment: are the <li><a href...> elements generated like expected ? Are their number corresponding to the amount of images you detect in $allfilesslides ?

Comment: @montueron Yes and Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the values of the bxSlider function ?

```
$j('.bxslider-2').show().bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 111,
            minSlides: 4,
            maxSlides: 7,
            moveSlides: 6,
            slideMargin: 10,
            speed: 1500,
            pager: false,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true,
            onSliderLoad: function () {
                // do funky JS stuff here
            }
        });
```

especially minSlides, maxSlides and moveSlides. Are you assigning that value depending on the length of the elements you detect ?

Comment: What is the `moveSlides` option

Comment: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified, example 4. "Here we see a new setting: moveSlides. This tells the carousel to move y slides each time next / prev is fired. If no value is supplied for moveSlides, the carousel will use the number of visible slides for this value."